# Is it possible get vim keybindings in MySQL Workbench query editor?

Tags: mysql, vim, mysql-workbench

I feel totally uncomfortable while typing without vim keybinding. Is it is possible to get vim keybinding in MySQL Workbench query editor?

Answer (score 2):

I found out there is no easy way to integrate vim with MySQL Workbench. But I found two better ways to use vim for writing MySQL query without any paid software like DataGrip or Jetbrain products.

1. **DBeaver** which is a free and opensource application, which is much better than MySQL Workbench in terms of performance and stability. You can use vim within its editor using Vrapper plugin. Here is an instruction of how you can install this plugin:
   https://shehuawwal.com/installing-vim-extension-module-for-dbeaver-with-vrapper/
2. Install mycli (best) or MySQL client in your machine and set the default editor as nvim/vim. use `\e` in command in mysql/mycli prompt to open your preferred editor. save and close the file to run the query you have written in the editor.

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ's DataGrip seems to be the most feasible solution at this stage.

You'll need to install IdeaVim plugin to make it work. Seems to work but IntelliJ is extremely slow.

**2022 Update:**
I'm using VIM at this stage, with the plugins DadBod by TPope and DadBod-UI...Not until Azure Data Studio provides MySQL support, this is working perfectly for me.

**2023 Update:**
Use Azure Data Studio. It supports VIM keybindings now.